# WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {} while using WebDriver with Safari 11 on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari

I have a selenium webdriver script which performs some regression tests on my application under test. The script works perfectly on Google Chrome, Firefox, IE, etc.

However, recently I tried running it on Safari (11.1.1) on Mac OS X (10.13.5), and my script fails with a weird message even when I call a simple line such as

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
```

The exception I get is as follows:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {}
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'Yethis-MacBook-Pro.local', ip: '192.168.2.197', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.5', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:375)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByTagName(RemoteWebDriver.java:441)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByTagName.findElement(By.java:334)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:360)
    at org.ycs.selenium.safari.App.execute(App.java:75)
    at org.ycs.selenium.safari.App.main(App.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:373)
    ... 5 more
```

Selenium Version: 3.0.1
Safari Version: 11.1.1
Java Version: 1.8
OS X version: 10.13.5

Edit:
This is my dependency configured in maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried doing a lot of search for this issue, but unfortunately, nothing showed up with Mac specific information.

Could anyone help me solve this problem please?

Thanks,
Sriram Sridharan

Comment: please share the html source code and your attepmt.

Comment: I'm sorry this is a client application, and I cannot share the HTML source. However, I can tell you that this problem happens only on few random pages, and the remaining pages have no issues. I however have ensured that there are no issues with respect to iFrames, window handles, etc. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: From exception StackTrace, do some search on this `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement`

Answer (score 3):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {}
```

...implies that WebDriverException was raised while *JVM* tried to cast the returned value into a *WebElement*.

However your main issue is as follows:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
```

---

### ClassCastException

[**ClassCastException**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) is thrown to indicate that the code has attempted to cast an object to a subclass of which it is not an instance. As an example, the following code generates a ClassCastException:

```
Object x = new Integer(0);
System.out.println((String)x);
```

---

### What went wrong

It is not clear about your usecase why you require to grab the `<body>` tag. But as per the following discussions:

- [java.lang.ClassCastException exception while clicking/inputing on any web object](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/2501)
- [WebDriver and Firefox 4+: this.getWindow() is null](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/1438)

There can be three possibilities of this error as follows:

- Your script/program was trying to access the `<body>` tag when the page was still loading perhaps when some *JavaScript* / *Ajax* was still active.
- Solution: Induce *WebDriverWait* for the *WebElement* to whom you desire to interact with as follows:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("elementID")));
  ```
- If you want to get the *Page Source* use **`getPageSource()`** method as follows:

  ```
  System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
  ```
- If the control of the program was within an `<iframe>` before trying to find the `<body>` tag, switch back to the **defaultContent** as follows:

  ```
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  ```

**Note**: As per best practices always keep your *Test Environment* updated with the latest releases.

- Update the *Selenium Client* dependency to **3.12.0**:

  - `selenium-java`:

    ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    ```
  - `selenium-server`:

    ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    ```

Comment: Hello Debanjan, Thanks for your reply. Answering your question first. I actually have no functional need to capture the <body> tag. It was just to demonstrate that I could not identify any element on the page, including the body tag. There were no iFrames in the previous page, though I added a switchTo().defaultContent() just to be sure. I also added a WebDriverWait as you mentioned, but the WebDriverWait statement itself threw the aforementioned error this time. Also, I don't think it waited for 20 seconds. The exception was almost instantaneous. Could you help me?