# RESOLVED: RSelenium error - com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap incompatible with java.lang.CharSequence

Tags: html, css, r, selenium, rselenium

I am trying to use RSelenium automate a data entry task for my job in which I must input some variables into an online system. There are 5 variables to enter, and my code works for all of them except for one, the "First Name" entry.

```
remDr$findElement("css selector", "#ctl00_CPHMain_frvProfile_txtFederatedUserID")$sendKeysToElement(list(NetID[i]))

remDr$findElement("css selector", "#ctl00_CPHMain_frvProfile_txtUserName")$sendKeysToElement(list(ID[i]))

remDr$findElement("css selector", "#ctl00_CPHMain_frvProfile_txtFirstName")$sendKeysToElement(list(First[i]))

remDr$findElement("css selector", "#ctl00_CPHMain_frvProfile_txtLastName")$sendKeysToElement(list(Last[i]))

remDr$findElement("css selector", "#ctl00_CPHMain_frvProfile_txtEmail")$sendKeysToElement(list(Email[i]))
```

The top two and bottom two both enter the data perfectly, but the middle snippet throws:

```
Selenium message:com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap incompatible with java.lang.CharSequence

Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

In my Google searching and troubleshooting I have never seen this error, and it's very strange to me that it only applies to one of my elements. Anyone able to help?

Edit: Here is the HTML of the page I am pulling from:

```
 <a href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$CPHMain$frvProfile$ctl02&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">Save & Close</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <table align="left" style="width: 100%">

            <tr>
        <td align="right">
                    <strong>
                        <label for="ctl00_CPHMain_frvProfile_txtFederatedUserID" id="ctl00_CPHMain_frvProfile_lblFederatedUserID">Federated User ID</label>
                    </strong>
                </td>
        <td colspan="2">
                    <input name="ctl00$CPHMain$frvProfile$txtFederatedUserID" type="text" id="ctl00_CPHMain_frvProfile_txtFederatedUserID" />

                    <span id="ctl00_CPHMain_frvProfile_rfvFederatedUserID" style="display:none;">*</span>

                    <span id="ctl00_CPHMain_frvProfile_cvFedID" style="display:none;"><br/>*Federated User ID already in use</span>
                </td>
    </tr>

            <tr>
        <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
        <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
    </tr>

            <tr>
                <td align="right">
                    <label for="ctl00_CPHMain_frvProfile_txtUserName" id="ctl00_CPHMain_frvProfile_lbltxtUserName">Username</label>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input name="ctl00$CPHMain$frvProfile$txtUserName" type="text" id="ctl00_CPHMain_frvProfile_txtUserName" />
                    <span id="ctl00_CPHMain_frvProfile_rfvUserName" style="display:none;">*</span>
                    <span id="ctl00_CPHMain_frvProfile_cvUserName" style="display:none;"><br/>*Username already in use</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
                <td align="right">
                    <label for="ctl00_CPHMain_frvProfile_txtFirstName" id="ctl00_CPHMain_frvProfile_lbltxtFirstName">First Name</label>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input name="ctl00$CPHMain$frvProfile$txtFirstName" type="text" id="ctl00_CPHMain_frvProfile_txtFirstName" />
                    <span id="ctl00_CPHMain_frvProfile_rfvFirstName" style="display:none;">*</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Edit 2: RESOLVED! I had messed something up when importing my csv. I had to make a new column with the same data in the same csv and for some reason that worked.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Selenium message:com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap incompatible with java.lang.CharSequence
```

...implies that an error occured while invoking `sendKeysToElement()` for the WebElement.

A bit more details about your usecase interms of the text based [HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)would would have helped us to analyze the issue in a better way. As you are able to fillup the **UserName** field, possibly the *username* is validated if it is a unique one and hence the **FirstName** field remain *non interactable*. Hence you see the error.

You need to induce some wait for the **FirstName** field to be *interactable*.

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant discussion in:

- [WebDriverException: Returned value cannot be converted to WebElement: {} while using WebDriver with Safari 11 on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51020225/webdriverexception-returned-value-cannot-be-converted-to-webelement-while-u/51023244#51023244)

Comment: I have been testing the code both individual lines at a time as well as as altogether. Even when I run the FirstName field alone it spits the error. I edited the HTML of the page I am trying to enter into the OP. Also, I tried a sys.sleep and it did not help the issue - is that what you meant by a "wait"? I am a novice/beginner coder.

Also, the fields do not validate in real time. I have to hit submit afterwards which I am waiting to code until I get this part down.